# How to check that the double expansion of something is empty?

Tags: macros, expansion

I'm using the listofitems package, which produce a list whose elements are accessable by

```
\LIST[n]
```

but in the manual I read that I need a double expansion.

In particular how do I chek that (the double expansion of) `\LIST[n]` is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand things twice by using `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter` (the first `\expandafter` steps over the second, the third expands the argument after `{` once, the first and third are removed, the second expands the argument after `{` the second time). If you need to expand the argument of a macro, you'll also need to put three `\expandafter` before it (this isn't necessary for `\detokenize` as it expands everything until it finds an opening brace; and it also isn't necessary for `\if`, as it expands everything until it finds two unexpandable tokens).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems}
\readlist\foo{12,abc,3,4,,}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\newcommand\iflistitememptyTF[2]
  {%
    \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#1[#2]}\relax
      \expandafter\@secondofthree
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\iflistitememptyTF\foo{5}{empty}{not empty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what `\providecommand` `\@secondofthree` and `\secondoftwo` do?

Comment: Ok, I see how to use with nested lis, just uses \foo{5,2} as argument.

Comment: @user126154 `\providecommand` defines a command if it isn't yet defined, `\@secondofthree` expands to the second of three arguments, and `\@secondoftwo` expands to the second of two arguments.